# Does every new view need a new layoutparams?

Tags: android

So let's say that I want to create multiple TextViews programatically inside a relative layout. It looks like with each new TextView I also have to create a new LayoutParams like so:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Then I add whatever rules I want using:

```
p.addrule(...,...);
```

It seems that I cannot use this single LayoutParams to set the rules for multiple TextViews. Is this a true statement?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the same LayoutParams for multiple views is fine, modulo the caveat that changing the LayoutParams before the views have been through layout will apply the changes to all the views.

If you're just looking to save code then you may look into LayoutParams' [copy constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#ViewGroup.LayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29). This allows you to create a new LayoutParams from the data in another LayoutParams without having the two refer to the same LayoutParams instance.

Answer (score 2):

After creating and constructing the correct LayoutParams instance you could use it for every View in that parent:

```
view1.setLayoutParams(params0);
```

If you want to have independent copies of params (which you want, I think), you can change it so:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(params0);
view1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Funny sidenote: that CopyConstructor will only copy the height and width, since it is the ViewGroup.RelativeLayouts CopyConstructor. Above API 19, you can call `new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)params0);`tto also copy the margins and rules that were specified.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the same LayoutParams object to multiple TextViews, they will share all of the settings.  This means if you change something in it, the change will apply to all TextViews.  In general, you will want to use a different instance for each TextView.